# Swift Align Leading Edge with Trailing Edge

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, storyboard

I have a label that I want as the x axis label on my graph, and I want to align the trailing edge of the label to the graph view, and also the top edge to the bottom edge of the graph view, how can I do this? I am building it via storyboard

storyboard screenshot with constraints
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I record my screen to get what you want :

https://giphy.com/gifs/JbnR5F1ZFogb7gSojT/fullscreen (Sorry for the gif-quality)

Just keep pressing `control` and drag your mouse from the UILabel to the graph view to do the same thing.

1. Add horizontal spacing
2. Add bottom constraint
3. Select the bottom constraint by clicking the blue line that represents it
4. Change relation to first item (your label) from `Bottom` to `Top` value

If I misunderstood what you want and you wanted the following:

[image]

Just select the **horizontal spacing** constraint by selecting the blue line that represents it, and adjust the constraint's settings with the following :

[image]